# What permissions are required to call /_api/hubsites and get results?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

We are trying to use the SharePoint REST API to retrieve the list of hubs a user has access to. When I, as a SharePoint admin call the api (`https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/_api/hubsites`) I get the list of hubs correctly. However when anyone else calls the api they get a empty response. They have contribute rights to the SharePoint home site as well as the Hub and all connected sites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on Microsoft [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/features/hub-site/rest-hubsites-method) , this RESTful service should be "callable" by any user with read permission to the site.

> Gets information about all hub sites that the current user can access.

Are you sure those users do have access to Hub sites? Can you share the empty responses you gerfrom those users calls?

Comment: The users all have Contribute access to the hubsite and all the associtated sites as well as read access to the 'home' site. Here is the response from a test user: `<feed xml:base="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/"><id>3fed1e8d-va0c-4r10-ra0b-f9sbd3ffg2e3</id><title/><updated>2020-09-28T18:50:24Z</updated><author><name/></author></feed>`